# Write an arraylist into excel java

Tags: java, excel

I have an array list and add to this list all the texts from checkboxes and textfields 
and i want to write this list in an excel file...Any ides? eg

```
public ArrayList<String> savelist = new ArrayList<>();
age = ageField.getText();
        city = poliField.getText();
        address = AddrField.getText();
        telephone = telField.getText();
     savelist.add("City "+ city);
    savelist.add("Address "+ address);
        savelist.add("Telephone "+ telephone);
    savelist.add("Age "+ age);
        savelist.add("Gender "+ gender);
        savelist.add("Pregnancy "+ prgn);
```

I have found the below code but i am confused

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
      HSSFSheet  Sheet  = workbook.createSheet();
for (int i=0; i<mylist.size(); i++) {
 HSSFRow  Row  = Sheet.createRow(i);
   Row.createCell(0).setCellValue( list1.get(i) );
   Row.createCell(1).setCellValue( list2.get(i) );
   Row.createCell(2).setCellValue( list3.get(i) );
}
```

Comment: And the question is? How to connect these two pieces of code?

Comment: Yes...how exactly can i write this list to an excel file!

Comment: You start by searching google for one of the countless examples

Comment: i search it to google but i am confused..what are those  list.get(i) .. Are something like mine city=field.getText?

Comment: We aren't a replacement for traditional learning. If you don't know what `list.get(i)` means then you still have a lot of personal research to do.

Comment: I know what list.get(i) is but i can't understand what list is that... never mind.,..i'll google it again and i'll make more research!Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! ^_^

```
try {

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("testinsert");
        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
        rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Results");

        int i = 1;
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        File sv = null;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel Files", "xls", "csv");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

        int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            sv = chooser.getSelectedFile();

            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(sv);

        } else {

            return;
        }

        while ( i<savelist.size()) {
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
            row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(savelist.get(i) );
            row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(savelist.get(i) );
            row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(savelist.get(i) );

            i++;

        }

        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Diagnosis.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data exported");
```

The only problem is that when i save the file i have to change manualy the extension... :\